# How can 2 NSData objects output the same HEX but be different when converted to char array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdata

So basically I have some NSData objects and a method which looks like this:

```
+ (NSData *)outputData:(NSData *)data andThisData:(NSData *)secondData {
    char cData[data.length];
    [data getBytes:&cData];

    char cSecondData[secondData.length];
    [secondData getBytes:&cSecondData];

    NSLog(@"NSData: %@, %@", data, secondData);
    NSLog(@"HEX: %x, %x",cData,cSecondData);
}
```

I'm getting this output for two separate NSData objects which look the same on the face of it:

```
 NSData: <dc4945fa a76fa1eb 6c3de73e acabf71c>, <c7a75cfc 11697878 14b95c2b 8680b60b ed553909 d199c12b 6e66df1d 20dce6e5 46ef9cf6 0aefa4ee bf98b0d1 6579a311>
    HEX: 5fbfe870, 5fbfe840

 NSData: <dc4945fa a76fa1eb 6c3de73e acabf71c>, <c7a75cfc 11697878 14b95c2b 8680b60b ed553909 d199c12b 6e66df1d 20dce6e5 46ef9cf6 0aefa4ee bf98b0d1 6579a311>
    HEX: 5fbfe820, 5fbfe7f0
```

As you can see the NSData output is exactly the same, but the `char` hex they produce is different (albeit very similar). This is throwing off some calculations and the output of further calculations, but I can't see why they would be different at all.

So in what situations would this occur? And how can I remedy it?

Many thanks. (If you need any more info please let me know).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not printing the data in the buffers. You're printing the pointers which the addresses of the two local arrays decay into. If you actually print the data, they will be the same:

```
NSMutableString *hex = [NSMutableString string], *secondHex = [NSMutableString string];
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(cData); i++) {
    [hex appendFormat:@"%02x", cData[i]];
    [secondHex appendFormat:@"%02x", cSecondData[i]];
}

NSLog(@"%@ %@", hex, secondHex);
```

Comment: Ah! That could be the issue! How would I do the former? This could be why my further calculations are messing up, because I'm using the memory address.

Comment: @ThomasClayson You need to deal with the fact that you have an array of `char`s. See update.

Comment: Ah that worked thank you! That made the issue obvious the data object wasn't an ASCII data object so it wasn't encoding to char properly. When I changed it to UInt8 instead it makes everything following work properly! :)